# Почему @font-face не вытеснило предыдущие методы объявления семейства шрифта?

Tags: html5, css3

Несмотря на появление в CSS3 правила `@font-face`, которое, казалось бы, должно полносью решить проблему отсутствия каких-либо шрифтов на стороне клиента, определение шрифта по старым версиям HTML и CSS всё ещё продолжает использоваться. Единственная причина существования по сей день длинных описаний типа `font-tamily: "PT Sans", "Arial", serif;`, которую я могу предположить - это совместимоть со старыми браузерами, но есть ли ещё какие-нибудь причины?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина [раз](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face):

> The @font-face CSS at-rule allows authors to specify online fonts to
>   display text on their web pages.
>
> @font-face CSS "над-правило" позволяет автором указать онлайн шрифты
>   для отображения текста на их веб-страницах.

Причина [два](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-family):

> The font-family CSS descriptor allows authors to specify the font for
>   an element.
>
> font-family CSS свойство позволяет авторам указать шрифт для элемента.

Простыми словами для этих элементов стоят разные задачи, которые они выполняют. К примеру, как сказано в вопросе, @font-face **объявляет** шрифт, а font-family уже его непосредственно **использует** для конкретного элемента.